# Unity 3D doesn't work anymore, just shows a menu on the top

Tags: unity, 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I no longer have Unity 3D in Ubuntu 11.10.  After [I reinstalled Unity 3D](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1850372), my desktop looks like this:

[image]

Any suggestions?