# compiz hiding unity and all menus

Tags: unity, menu, unity-dash, gnome-classic

After updating to Ubuntu 11.10, I was severly disturbed by Dash and wanted to go back to Ubuntu Classic. So I tried to read up, and found Compiz SettingsManager. In there, I clicked "on" never hide menus. For some reason this made all my menus at the top of the screen (volume, network, my login identity, and shutoff, etc) disappear - as well as the quickstart menu to the left (Unity).

I am not very technical, so I have a hard time finding any programs now, and I just got on the internet by clicking on a link in a document, that I was fortunate to have on my Desktop. Without it, I wouldn't be able to ask for help.

What I wish for is a) to get back the menu at the top, b) to restore the Ubuntu Classic without the irritating launcher and Dash, c) these two things to not disappear every time there is a new version of Ubuntu.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity 3D doesn't work anymore, just shows a menu on the top](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63921/unity-3d-doesnt-work-anymore-just-shows-a-menu-on-the-top)

Comment: Try the question I just linked, see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

To get some sort of Ubuntu classic, install the gnome-shell and gnome-session-fallback packages. To do that, type in a Terminal (Dash->Terminal) window:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-session-fallback
```

Then reboot, and on the session selection screen, select GNOME fallback or GNOME Classic (forgot which one it was)

Comment: I tried this, but there is no session selection screen and no GNOME Fallback or GNOME Classic, and there are still no menus, so I cannot select any session settings. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Okay, I found it. Thanks. However, it doesn't seem to be a way to add new program starters to the menu bar. Or is there?

Answer (score 0):

i have just installed 11.10, not upgraded from 11.04 (i hate that).

i installed compizconfig-settings-manager AND **compiz-fusion-plugins-extra**

did some tweaks for the unity dash

rebooted (to check boot logs)

surprise :
i can see 'Ubuntu Classic' in the login menu

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire up the settings manager again and make sure the Unity plugin is checked, or you can try to reset unity's configuration:

- [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

It looks like someone gave you bad advice on how to set up classic. Here's how to revert to a more classic session:

- [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

Comment: About the first thing, this is the result of trying to reset Unity in the terminal:

Comment: (several things done)
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x3c000a4!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you shouldprobably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x3c000a7!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you shouldprobably file a bug about this.

Comment: @LennartGuldbrandsson Add this information to your question, the way the site works is you keep adding detail to your question, which bumps it. The more information you keep adding the easier it will be for the next person to help, thanks!