# Missing launcher, top panel without icons, an ATI driver problem?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

After upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10, the following problems occurs when accesing in ubuntu mode (3D): the launcher is missing, top panel without icons on the right side, and I can only restart with Terminal (Alt-T and then sudo reboot). No problems in 2D. It occurs on my PC with AMD Athlon (tm) II X4 640 Processor, Radeon HD5670 and both with the 32-bit and 64 bits versions of Ubuntu. 
Both versions work well on an older PC with AMD Athlon 64 x2 Dual Core 4200 + processor, and an Nvidia integrated graphics card (C61 GeForce 6150SE nForce 430).
Could it be a problem with the ATI driver?

Comment: Can you please post the output of this command: `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay.jlotero2@cristina-GA-MA78LMT-S2:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p 
OpenGL vendor string:   ATI Technologies Inc. 
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 5670 
OpenGL version string:  4.1.11005 Compatibility Profile Context 

Not software rendered:    yes 
Not blacklisted:          yes 
GLX fbconfig:             yes 
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes 
GL npot or rect textures: yes 
GL vertex program:        yes 
GL fragment program:      yes 
GL vertex buffer object:  yes 
GL framebuffer object:    yes 
GL version is 1.4+:       yes 

Unity 3D supported:       yes

Comment: Closed - since OP has confirmed that the dupe link is the resolution (see comment below answer)

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that your computer is capable of running Unity 3D.

Try this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63921/unity-3d-doesnt-work-anymore-just-shows-a-menu-on-the-top/63937#63937) in another question:

> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> for a terminal and run cssm
>
> re-enable your 'unity' plugin
>
> you also may then need to run a
>
> unity --reset

If you don’t have CCSM installed, run `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Comment: Solved!
I think the problem arose after trying to reduce the size of the icons in Launcher (with ccsm).
Although I finally decided to keep the default size, the Ubuntu Unity plugin remained disabled.
After re-run ccsm as advised, to try to re enable it, appeared several dialogues (in spanish, the version I'm using).
The first:

Comment: Some of the key links and the edge of Ubuntu Unity Plugin Plugin conflicts occur with other plugins. Do you want to solve?
-Ignoring conflicts
-Resolve Conflicts (selected)

Then came another 5 dialogues, with the options:
Ignore and apply ... (the choice of reference)
They do not apply ... (reference option)
Off ... (reference option)
In all these cases, I selected the first option.
Then the Ubuntu Unit plugin re-enabled, and now everything works perfectly.

(for more details of each dialogue, see paste.ubuntu.com/710381/)
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: OK, so the problem was in fact that Unity plugin was disabled. And the dialogs that appeared are “conflicts” of Unity plugin with other Compiz plugins. I’m glad you solved it! Saludos