# How do I recover Unity3D lost from Compiz config change?

Tags: unity, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity 3D doesn't work anymore, just shows a menu on the top](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63921/unity-3d-doesnt-work-anymore-just-shows-a-menu-on-the-top)

I am a rank newbie switching from windows 7.  I can't stand some of the default Unity behavior such as why are all my windows up in the top left corner?  With a large display that hurts my neck.  So I looked online and I installed the Compiz Config thingy.  Great.  Now I have NO desktop at all.  Just the menu bar at the top.

I looked up how to uninstall and reinstall Unity.  All the instructions point to other problems ... even other operating systems (Windows??? from an Ubuntu forum no less).  Can someone please tell me how to fix Unity?  I don't care about settings or anything.  I just don't want to reinstall Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to get a terminal and then issue:

```
rm -rf .compiz-1
```

and your unity session will come back before your eyes..

I [do not recommend ccsm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it); it is very dangerous, as you have discovered.

Comment: Thank you for your direct and simple answer.  I was able to access the terminal and I did as you suggested ... nothing happened.  I am still without the Unity3D desktop.  I had to log out with CTRL-ALT-DEL.  I am writing this from the Unity2D desktop.  I will remove CCSM as per your recommendation.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how new you are to Ubuntu, so don't be insulted if I tell you something you already know ;)

Since you can login using Unity-2d, open the file browser and press Ctrl-H. Find the .conf folder and rename it to something like .conf-backup. Restart, and try to login. If this doesn't work, there definitely more things you could try.

If you want help fixing Unity to they way you like (safely) or installing another desktop environment better suited to your tastes, just ask another question ;) (Since you are a former Windows 7 user you might find KDE very easy to use)