# Unity broken after logging into GNOME?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Unity seems to have broken itself!

I logged out of a Unity session and logged back into a GNOME/Openbox session to try out the GNOME Shell.

I logged in however, the Gnome Shell didn't seem to start up, and I was left literally staring at my desktop wallpaper.

I rebooted my laptop and logged in back into a regular Ubuntu session. However, instead of Unity starting up, the only desktop environment I get is my desktop wallpaper with a menu bar running along the top.

No tray, no unity launcher, no lenses, nothing. What went wrong here? How can I get my Unity working again? And how can I try out Gnome Shell without seemingly breaking my Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Can you see if this is the problem? http://askubuntu.com/questions/63921/unity-3d-doesnt-work-anymore-just-shows-a-menu-on-the-top

Comment: Apparently Openbox and GNOME don't play nicely together unless you resort to workarounds. You may find this [Openbox wiki page](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:GNOME/Openbox) a useful resource. Any particular reason you want to use Openbox with GNOME Shell?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,